# NSInternalInconsistencyException Fix with Facebook Login

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there's a lot of posts about this error but since this error seems to cover a lot of ground, I figured it would be fair to post the issues I'm having.

I have this app that uses login via facebook and I finished it last night, worked fine, and ran it once this morning and it crashed.

Unlike a lot of the other people that have this error, I am not using NIB files, I'm using storyboards. Everything, to the best of my knowledge, is spelled correctly, that is, all the names of my view controllers and what not. The code I'm using to set up the facebook login is directly from facebook itself. Only the names of the view controllers last. have changed.

```
2012-11-02 15:06:50.167 App[18840:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught                exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/B95B9738-17D5-46E9-AF45-5E4CCD825EAB/App.app> (loaded)' with name 'WLLoginViewController''
```

ion

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: I can give you this code because this is where it crashes:

```
self.mainViewController = [[WLLoginViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"AppViewController" bundle:nil];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                      initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

It crashes on the last line.

If anyone has any ideas I'll...idk marry you or something.

Comment: You might want to think about posting some code, or maybe any other error logs that are generated. If you are not sure, you can set an exception breakpoint XCode and break on the uncaught exception.

Comment: Already am and I can't because its a business project. That error message is the only one I get.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, I've come to this conclusion:

Facebook's current tutorial doesn't work with people that use Storyboards in their iOS apps. I already filled a bug report with them so hopefully they'll update that. Because my project uses storyboards, there is no NIB file so if there's no NIB file, it can never find it and will ALWAYS throw the above error.